# Bootstrap's card component example with 'kitchen sink' not working correctly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to use the kitchen sink example from Bootstrap's card but if I use it at my site then it will not render the top border from the first list item like in the example and it's driving me crazy.

This is what is should look like: [example on bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#kitchen-sink)

And if I paste the exact same code on my end (and on JSFiddle too) then it looks like this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="card-body">
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing? How can I add the top border like in the example without too much hacky css/code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like *after* 4.1 there was a slight change to remove the top border of the first item in the `list-group`...

```
.list-group-flush .list-group-item:first-child {
    border-top-width: 0px;
}
```

So when you use older 4.1 the border is there: https://codeply.com/p/2n5yUhtPMY
but, with newer 4.4 the border is gone: https://www.codeply.com/p/BJwh8TtAth

A simple workaround would be to use `border-bottom` on the `card-body` above:

```
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="//placehold.it/600" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body border-bottom">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item">(fixed with border-bottom)</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="card-body">
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Another option is to use `border-top` on the first `list-group-item`

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, exactly what I was looking for!